# JSON grouping list view formating

Tags: json, listview, sharepoint-online

I have grouping list view in Sharepoint Online. And I need format column headers (which groups items) in this view. Change font color, background, etc.

In the Team Site template there is Content Editor Web Part, and I can use CSS there, but I have Communicaton Site template and it's does not support this webpart. And I should use JSON formatting.

Maybe there are some examples? All examples, which I found, formats only list items.